# Access ResultsView from object type

Tags: c#

How to access ResultsView from an object of type Object?

```
Object table = null;
Class.CallSomeMethod( ref table);
```

`table` has resultsview and I am not sure how to access that?

Answer (score 1):

Just cast `table` variable to appropriate type:

```
((SomeTypeWithResultView)table).ResultsView
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object table = null;    
var varTable = ((SomeTableType)table).ResultsView;
method(ref varTable);
```